# Cambiar a negrita un string de una cadena

Tags: vb.net, .net, string, richtextbox

Estoy haciendo un programa en `VB` y tengo una cadena de texto, la cual la agrego a un `RichTextBox`, pero quiero agregarle algunas cosas.

Lo que quiero lograr es que el texto sea como el siguiente:

"**Más de la mayoría de las mediciones** que se realizaron de la presión del domo sobrepasan el límite con un **80%** del total."

No sé si es posible lograr eso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es posible, usa la propiedad [RTF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) para convertir a `bold` el texto:

```
    Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("{\rtf1\ansi")
    sb.Append("\b Más de la mayoría de las mediciones\b0  que se realizaron de la presión del domo sobrepasan el límite con un \b 80%\b0  del total.")
    sb.Append(" \par}")


    RichTextBox1.Rtf = sb.ToString()
```

Es importante colocar correctamente los contenedores, `\b` y `\b0`, a ambos se les agrega un espacio:

```
\b Palabra en negrita\b0
```

Mediante este método mostrarías texto en "negritas" dentro de tu `RichTextBox`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]